# Iterate over a array and returning the next and the element before current

Tags: ruby, arrays

How may i fetch next and before current element from array while iterating array with each.

```
array.each do |a|
   # I want to fetch next and before current element.
end
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) What is the "previous" element at the beginning and the "next" element at the end? 2) Should the `next` element be the `current` element of the next iteration (that is, after the group `[ar[4], ar[5], ar[6]]`, should the next group be `[ar[5], ar[6], ar[7]]` or `[ar[7], ar[8], ar[9]]`)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Take look at [`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) method:

```
[nil, *array, nil].each_cons(3){|prev, curr, nxt|
  puts "prev: #{prev} curr: #{curr} next: #{nxt}"
}

prev:  curr: a next: b
prev: a curr: b next: c
prev: b curr: c next:
```

If you like, you can wrap it in new Array method:

```
class Array
  def each_with_prev_next &block
    [nil, *self, nil].each_cons(3, &block)
  end
end
#=> nil

array.each_with_prev_next do |prev, curr, nxt|
  puts "prev: #{prev} curr: #{curr} next: #{nxt}"
end
```

Comment: How about `[nil, *array, nil]` instead of `[nil]+array+[nil]`?

Comment: Great! I hate `+` variant, but I thought there isn't anything prettier. I'll update the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: if someone is looking for a way to "map" the elements instead of just iterate over them  you can do something like `1..9).each_cons(2).map { |a| a }`

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003137) to get the index of each element as you iterate, and use that to get the surrounding items.

```
array.each_with_index do |a, i|
  prev_element = array[i-1] unless i == 0
  next_element = array[i+1] unless i == array.size - 1
end
```